# WrongBackend at /login/facebook/ Incorrect authentication service "facebook"

Tags: python, django, facebook

Hi I am trying to do facebook login to my site. I am using django-social-auth for it.

My settings part is:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'facebook app id here'
FACEBOOK_API_SECERET = 'api secret here'

FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'user_location', 'user_photos']

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackened',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/post_login/'
in urls:

url(r'', include('social_auth.urls'))
```

and in template:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}">facebook</a>
```

the error trace is this:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/facebook/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'djrill',
 'bootstrapform',
 'djcelery',
 'djcelery_email',
 'social_auth',
 'smbhero',
 'apps.common',
 'apps.account',
 'apps.company',
 'apps.content')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/mnt/www/smb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/mnt/www/smb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/decorators.py" in wrapper
  28.                 raise WrongBackend(backend)

Exception Type: WrongBackend at /login/facebook/
Exception Value: Incorrect authentication service "facebook"
```

what is it that i am doing wrong ? what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#exceptions Are you sure that your backend has a valid URL?

Comment: @shashank what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your backend:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackened', <----
)
```